# Local dependency not found

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a project containing two (binary) packages, front- and backend.  Both are created & managed by cargo independently. In the frontend, I want to access some types declared in the backend, so I added to the frontend’s `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies.myapp-backend]
path = "../myapp-backend"
```

This matches my folder structure and `cargo-run` does not complain. Yet I can not use the crate in the frontend: When I add `extern crate myapp-backend` (or one of the variants with or without a `_` instead of `-`) to my frontend’s `main.rs`, the compiler yells at me that it can’t find the crate.

To check wether the whole dependency statement in the Cargo.toml is evaluated at all, I flipped some letters which gave me an instant compilation error (it therefore *is* evaluated). Also, I exchanged the importing statement with `use myapp-backend`, again with variations on the hyphen, directly, which results in the expected `no 'myapp_backend' external crate`. I even used the alternative notation for an external dependency, with no effect:

```
myapp-backend = {path = "../myapp-backend"}
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something stupid simple, but after reading Cargo’s documentation as well as Stack Overflow up and down for two days now, I dare to ask. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use an executable (crate with a *main.rs* file) as a dependency. But you could move all shared things into a 3. library crate and use that as a dependency in both executables.

Comment: I think that qualifies for stupid simple. Thank you! Interesting though that I never came across this fact, despite the fact that I read the official language book’s chapter on Cargo and dependencies. It must either completely have slipped my attention or what I’m trying to do it is considered an edge case/too advanced for the book’s scope.